# What category to use when add Facebook to an iOS app with create an App on facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to setup an app on facebook on my developer dashboard so users can log in with Facebook to my iOS game, when I click on "create an app" I have to choose a category, but I can never remember what category it should be, should it be the "Apps for pages" option? or should I actually choose the games category? isn't the latter all about games which are actually on Facebook? as apposed to apps for pages, which is just creating an app so you have the App Id to use in your iOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose the Games category.

The category you choose affects your listing in the Facebook Application Center, which you can use even if your game is not available on the Facebook Canvas.